# Transform an array of objects and a simple array with python

Tags: python, arrays, django

I would like to ask for help on how to transform this arry result into a simple array of the type array=['a', 'b','c', ... 'aaa', 'aab' ...] that I want to be able to call the elements that are in the array only with indices ex: array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmqf7.png) ='a'; arry[2]='b' and so on
To help you understand what I want, see the result in this py file that I share here, try to run it on your machine and see the result it gives.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
import itertools

def iter_all_strings():
    for size in itertools.count(1):
        for s in itertools.product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=size):
            yield "".join(s)
lista=[]
for s in itertools.islice(iter_all_strings(), 1000):
    lista.append(s)
    print (lista[-1:1000])
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify? I think your code is already doing this... `lista` is a list of strings.

Comment: You can try to list only the letter that is in position 2 for example ( list[2] ) this should return me only a specific letter that is in this position , it would just be b, that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your code solves your problem, `lista` is an array of strings and indexed access works on the array of strings. For example, accessing `lista[2]` yields `c` and it works.

Comment: it's not working like you say
can you share me the result that appears on your screen?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are printing inside your for loop, so it will render each element separately in your terminal.

```
for s in itertools.islice(iter_all_strings(), 1000):
    lista.append(s)
    print (lista[-1:1000])
```

Secondly, you are slicing your array, and `array[-1]` index corresponds to the last element of the array. So, even if you move outside of the for loop it will just return `['all']`.

So, just move the print out of the loop scope and remove the slicing.

```
...
for s in itertools.islice(iter_all_strings(), 1000):
    lista.append(s)
    
print (lista)
```

That returns the result you want. Then you can look for elements using indexes. Note that indexes starts at 0 not 1!

```
# returns 'a'
print(lista[0])

# returns 'b'
print(lista[1])

# Returns 'all' (the last element)
print(lista[-1])
```

Comment: in my case it was printing many letters because the print(list) was inside the for